# Find the value of $x$ for which the gradient is zero.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $y=(x-3) \sqrt{x-1} $. Find the value of $x$ for which the gradient is zero.

The derivative of the function is $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x-3}{2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x-1}.$$

Comment: please help me in editing i am not very familiar with the equations here

Comment: @Lazy The OP has found $\frac{dy}{dx}$ here. That's half the battle.

Comment: True my bad. Apologies.

Comment: i am not been able to get the value of x i dont know how to simplify further  @LazyStupidGuy

Comment: You simply put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ as the derivative is the gradient in a point, kinda. 

With gradient you mean slope right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is correct.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x-3}{2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x-1} = \frac{(x-3) +\cdot 2\sqrt{x -1}\cdot \sqrt{x-1}) + }{2\sqrt{x-1}} = \frac{(x-3)+ 2(x-1)}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$$

So, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies (x-3)+ 2(x-1) = 0$$

Now simplify: $$(x-3)+2(x-1) = 0 \iff x-3+2x - 2 = 0\iff 3x-5= 0 \iff x = \frac{5}3$$

Comment: thanks you are really a champion

Comment: You are welcome, Tayyab!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, gradient refers to functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  By "gradient" do you mean "derivative"?  If so, perhaps this is correct?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x-3}{2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x-1}.$$

Setting the derivative to $0$,

$$ \frac{x-3}{2\sqrt{x-1}} = -\sqrt{x-1} $$

$$x-3 = -2(x-1)$$

$$x = \frac53$$

Comment: I think he means slope.